# What are 3 items in a Swift method parameter for?

Tags: swift

Example:

```
mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double)
```

The first parameter takes a Double and saves it in that method scope as `deltaX`. However, what are `y` and `deltaY`?

I read this and can't find anything about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Comment: There're only two parameters and one of them has an external name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Swift mimics Objective C's named parameters (pseudo naming of arguments). Its pretty easy to break down.

```
mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double)
                1        2      3     4   5       6
```

1. Beginning of method name

   First parameter name

   First parameter type

   Second part of method name

   Second parameter name

   Second parameter type

In this example, the method is actually called `moveByX:y:` The equivalent Objective C method definition would look like this.

```
- (void)moveByX:(Double)deltaX y:(Double)deltaY
```

When calling this method, the second part of the name is included alone with the rest of the arguments.

```
var dub = Double(0.5)
moveByX(dub, y: dub)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar to Objective-C. I just jumped on iOS with Swift. So is this way of doing things optional?

Comment: @user83039 You don't have to name functions like this, but it is encouraged. The methods are supposed to be self documenting and descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

In your example,

- `y` is the [external parameter name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_255),
- `deltaY` is the local parameter name, and
- `Double` is the type of the parameter.

If you are familiar with Objective-C, this corresponds to a method with the following declaration:

```
-(void)moveByX:(double)deltaX y:(double)deltaY;
```

Comment: just curiously, won't this be more readable? -(void)moveByX:(double)deltaX moveByY:(double)deltaY;

Comment: @SamB The idea behind external names is to make the invocation "read like English". Repeating `moveBy` in front of `Y` would move us further away from that goal.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in swift have both an external parameter name and a local parameter name. External is defined first then external, if only one is defined swift compiler puts in the defaults.

Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names both local and external parameter names by default.

In the example, "y" is the external parameter used  when calling the method, "deltaY" is the variable name used in the internal calculations of that function.

You can also use _ to signify that you don't want a parameter to have an external name. 
# is used for shorthand when both your external and internal name are the same.

Examples

1)

```
func exampleFunction(externalVarName1 localVarName1: Int, externalVarName2  localVarName2: Int) {}
```

is called like this:

```
 exampleFunction(externalVarName1: 0, externalVarName2: 0)
```

2)

```
func exampleFunction2(autocompleteHintName: Int, autocompleteHintName2: Int) {}
```

is called like this

```
exampleFunction2(0, 0)
```

3)

```
func exampleFunction3(#nameForBoth: Int, #nameForBoth2: Int) {}
```

is called like this

```
exampleFunction3(nameForBoth: 0, nameForBoth2: 0)
```

4)

```
func exampleFunction4(nameForBoth nameForBoth: Int, nameForBoth2 nameForBoth2: Int) {}
```

is the same as 3) but throws a warning that the # shorthhand can be used. called like this

```
exampleFunction4(nameForBoth: 0, nameForBoth2: 0)
```

5)

```
func exampleFunction5(_: Int, _: Int) {}
```

is called like this

```
 exampleFunction5(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`deltaX` and `deltaY` are the parameter names when you are writing the function. However, when you call the function it will be called as `movebyX(val, y: val)` where `val` is replaced by the Double you are passing into the function. The y in the middle is essentially to help the readability of the function when it is called and is common practice in swift to make your code as readable as possible (the person calling your function can easily tell what each parameter is without looking at the function header).